# Disable data refresh google data studio

Tags: refresh, looker-studio

Possible refresh frequency in Google Data Studio:

- 15 Minutes
- 1 Hour
- 4 Hours
- 12 Hours
- Custom, however at least once every 12 hours

Can I disable refresh on my Datasources or make them less often?

The thing is that during the updating of data extra money is spent, and I would like this does not happen.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, the possible solution is to create 'extracted data' from an existing data source.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to your Google Data Studio dashboard
2. Add new data source, you need 'Extract Data' in the connectors list
3. Select an existing data source to extract from
4. Select the dimensions and metrics to extract by dragging them from the Available Fields list onto the targets, or by clicking Add. All the fields you add appear in the list on the far right.
5. Click 'SAVE AND EXTRACT'

Here's the link
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9019969?hl=en